# Send an Arraylist of an object from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I need to duplicate an **ArrayList** from one activity from another.
This is an **ArrayList** of an object that I named **Dias**, and it contains a String and a boolean:

```
Arraylist {Dias}  // Dias contains(String Dias, boolean estado)
```

And I have to pass this ArrayList to other activity.

My Dias class:

```
public class Dias {

  private String Dia;
  private boolean estado;

//CONSTRUCTOR DE LA CLASE//
  public Dias(String Dia, boolean estado) {
      this.Dia = Dia;
      this.estado = estado;
  }

//GETTERS Y SETTERS DE LA CLASE//

  public String getDia() {
      return Dia;
  }

  public void setDia(String dia) {
      Dia = dia;
  }

  public boolean isChekeado() {
      return estado;
  }

  public void setChekeado(boolean chekeado) {
      estado = chekeado;
  }
```

}

My Primary Class:

```
 public class Primera extends Activity {
    ArrayList<Dias> dias = new ArrayList<Dias>();
     //OnClick Method
    public void lanzar2(View view){
      dias.add(new Dias("Lu", false));
      dias.add(new Dias("MAr", false));
      Intent i = new Intent();
      Bundle b = new Bundle();
      b.putParcelableArrayList("arreglo", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) dias);
      i.putExtras(b);
      i.setClass(this, ListasActivity.class);
      startActivity(i);
   }

}
```

How can I send my **Arraylist** to another activity?, I just don't understand how does it work(parcelable) and also I don't know the syntax to use it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another simple method is to serialize it in your own way.

**For example**:

If you have 5 elements in your arraylist like `"hello", "how" , "are", "you", "brother"`. You can loop through the arraylist and make a string as `hello,how,are,you,brother`

```
String serializedString = "";
for(String anElement:arrayList)
    serilaizedString = serializedString + "," +anElement;
```

and send it to another activity using **putExtra** method of Intent.

And in the receiving end, you can split the text using **split(",")** then you will get an array which you can change to array list again if needed.

```
String[] myArray = recievedString.split(",");
List<String> myList = new List<String>();
for(String anElement:myList)
    myList.add(anElement);
```

Now you have myList as the array list.

**P.S.** Your strings shouldn't contain any comma though. So for cases with comma, you can use something like `$` or `%` or what ever is comfortable for case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the interface Parcelable in the object Dias.  You can see more about how to do it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Besides that you would send through an Intent that you use to start the other activity the ArrayList using the method:

)">intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(nameToSaveAs, yourList)

Then you `startActivity(intent)` and you can receive the data in the other activity with `getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(nameToSaveAs);` You will probably have to cast it, but that is the basic steps to pass ArrayLists.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass it either using Serialization or by using Parcelable interface. Refer to this for Parcelable interface http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html.